# Запуск скрипта в заданное время

Tags: тайминги, php

Привет, ребята!

Подскажите мне, пожалуйста, можно ли назначит запуск PHP-скрипта по времени?

Например, 18:00. Скрипт сканирует БД, находит обновление, выполняет функцию (например, рассылки). Такое вообще возможно? Если да, то как или чем такое реализовать?

А можно как-то принять email скриптом PHP?

Comment: Вероятно, вам нужен cron.

Comment: СПАСИБО! А можно как-то принять email скриптом PHP?

Answer (score 3):

Да, планировщик заданий CRON вам в этом поможет. Если крона на сервере нет, по каким либо причинам, и вы не можете его поставить, воспользуйтесь [`cron online`](http://mywebcron.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Cron. Меня удивляет, что это уже, наверно, 5-6 вопрос с таким заголовком, а Хэшкод все еще не подсказывает ответ.